# Flask dynamic route not working - Real Python

Tags: python, flask

I'm working through RealPython and I'm having trouble with the flask dynamic route.

Everything seemed to work until the dynamic route. Now if I try to enter a "search query" (i.e. localhost:5000/test/hi) the page is not found. localhost:5000 still works fine.

```
# ---- Flask Hello World ---- #

# import the Flask class from the flask module
from flask import Flask

# create the application object
app = Flask(__name__)


# use decorators to link the function to a url
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/hello")
# define the view using a function, which returns a string
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

# start the development server using the run() method
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()


# dynamic route
@app.route("/test/<search_query>")
def search(search_query):
    return search_query
```

I can't see that other people using RealPython have had an issue with the same code, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: So did you put the dynamic route after `app.run()`?

Comment: Well, your code can works good at here. `localhost:5000/test/hi`, `localhost:5000` or `localhost:5000/hello` will return the correct string and I didn't get a 404 error.

Comment: It worked after restarting my computer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason why this is not working is because flask never learns that you have another route other `/` and `/hello` because your program gets stuck on `app.run()`.

If you wanted to add this, all you need to do would be to add the new route *before* calling `app.run()` like so:

```
# ---- Flask Hello World ---- #

# import the Flask class from the flask module
from flask import Flask

# create the application object
app = Flask(__name__)


# use decorators to link the function to a url
@app.route("/")
@app.route("/hello")
# define the view using a function, which returns a string
def hello_world():
    return "Hello, World!"

# dynamic route
@app.route("/test/<search_query>")
def search(search_query):
    return search_query

# start the development server using the run() method
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", debug=True, port=5000)
```

Now this will work.

> Note: You don't need to change the run configurations inside of `app.run`. You can just use `app.run()` without any arguments and your app will run fine on your local machine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try using the entire URL instead of just the IP address.